# Pre-populate HTML form table from database using Django

Tags: python, django, database, forms, populate

I have a class-based view (**IndexView** at *views.py*) that shows a table with all the data stored in the database.
This view is rendered in *index.html* using a `def get_queryset(self)` to obtain all the data. No issues yet.

The difficult part for me is trying to do it using a form, to be able to modify and save the **amount** column.
I have no issues with the POST part, where I use AJAX to save the new values.
Where I'm having issues is getting the initial values from the database to populate a Django Form (*forms.py*)

I tried using `initial` argument in the definition of the form fields (at *forms.py*), even overriding `__init__` at the form definition, **but I don't know how to get "one value"**. I mean, the closer I've been in my tests was populating a **MultipleChoiceField** with:
`forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.order_by('code__name'))`
(achieving a multiple choice field of `Item object (1), Item object (2), etc.`)

But how do you populate a single **IntegerField** or **CharField** with the content of the database to show a form-based table field in the template?

I'm trying first with a single item (to try to understand how to reference one item/value to populate them using the database) before doing it with the whole table:

*index.hml:*

```
...
  <form class='my-ajax-form' method='POST' action='.' data-url='{{ request.build_absolute_uri|safe }}'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_table|safe}}
    <button type='submit'>Save changes</button>
  </form>
...
```

*models.py*:

```
class Code(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey(Code, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

*forms.py:*

```
class ItemForm(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField(max_length=6)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = forms.IntegerField()
```

*views.py:*

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView, AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'inventory/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'items_list'
    form_class = ItemForm

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
```

I checked these docs & some similar old issues, but I tried some of the suggestions/examples with no success:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example
- https://www.webforefront.com/django/formprocessing.html
- [Pre-populating Django Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585031/pre-populating-django-forms)
- [Populate a django form with data from database in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789466/populate-a-django-form-with-data-from-database-in-view#)

I'm using Django 2.0.2

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:
Trying to do something using UpdateView as andi suggests. Added (trying to get one value by id):

```
class ItemUpdate(UpdateView):
    form_class = JoinForm

    def get_object(self,queryset=None):
        obj = Item.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['2'])
        return obj
```

And pointed url to `path('', views.ItemUpdate.as_view(), name='index')` but always get `KeyError: '2'`

Comment: I am not sure using django forms is accurate in your case. For a similar need, I use jquery editinplace (https://github.com/siebertm/jquery-edit-in-place): it's simple and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using generic `from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView`
 straight on model?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview

views.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, CharField, Textarea
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

from demo.models import Item


class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    description = CharField(widget=Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['code', 'amount']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        item = super(ItemForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        item.code.description = self.cleaned_data['description']
        item.code.save()

    def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):
        if field_name == 'description':
            return self.instance.code.description
        else:
            return super(ItemForm, self).get_initial_for_field(field, field_name)


class ItemUpdateView(UpdateView):

    form_class = ItemForm
    model = Item

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('item-detail', kwargs={'pk': 1})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


from demo.views import ItemUpdateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'items/<int:pk>/', ItemUpdateView.as_view(), name='item-detail')
]
```

/templates/demo/item_form.html

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

If something regarding settings or config is unclear please refer to the repo with demo: https://github.com/andilabs/cbv

### UPDATE

added modelformset producing what you need in ListView

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory


class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Item

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ItemListView, self).get_context_data()
        formset = modelformset_factory(Item, form=ItemForm)()
        data['formset'] = formset
        return data
```

this just displays data in forms, you have take care of rest.

Comment: Hi! But that's for create an "edit button" with its own URL or something similar, isn't it? I don't know how I can use UpdateView to populate the initial form.

Yesterday I was reading this one:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/09/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-6.html

Comment: Just give it a try. Copy example code from tutorial and see how it works. Form for that view will be generated automatically on the go.

Comment: I tried to do it using UpdateView, but I think I'm not doing it the right way... (added it at the end of my post)
(ref: https://chriskief.com/2015/01/19/create-or-update-with-a-django-modelform/ )

Comment: @AbelPaz provide there all snippets of modelform too.

Comment: Do you mean my forms.py? It's in my post

Comment: @AbelPaz I fully updated it to the working version. Also added github repo url

Comment: Thanks andilabs. Ok, this is using items/<int:pk> as the URL.
I'll check your Github repo, but I think I miss how to show that ListView (in items/) as a pre-populated form (not as a simple list), and not just one item using the URL items/<int:pk>.

Comment: @AbelPaz you should easily specialise that code into grids using django `formsets`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: @AbelPaz see updated answer. Hopefully it will help you a lot!

Comment: Yeah, looks nice! Thanks. I'll try it in a few hours.
Anyway, the "def save..." method won't work with this formset right? I think I should use formset.save() in other place (not sure where right now) >.<

Comment: the method save() will be actually called for each of the form instance when calling `formset.save()` there is iteration over all forms done and save() is executed. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L655

Comment: I have no idea where to use formset.save >.< Tried different ways and places, but no success. Anyway, this is beyond my question. I'll keep trying...
Thank you so so much @andilabs.

Comment: I finally posted it as another question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350041/saving-class-based-view-formset-items-with-a-new-virtual-column

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of loading data into forms, as far as I know:

- In views.py

You are using `FormView` [CBV](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) which has a func called `get_intial`:

```
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['<form-field>'] = <initial-value>
        return initial
```

- In forms.py

You can override the **init** func:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['<form-field>'].initial = <initial-value>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is iterate through the item list, and set the value attribute of the input tag of each field to form.field_name.value