# Saving class-based view formset items with a new "virtual" column

Tags: python, django, save, formset

I have a table inside a form, generated by a formset.

In this case, my problem is to save all the items after one of them is modified, adding a new "virtual" column as the sum of other two (that is only generated when displaying the table, not saved).
I tried different ways, but no one is working.

**Issues**:

- This `save` is not working at all. It worked when it was only one form, but not for the formset
- I tried to generate the column `amount` as a `Sum` of `box_one` and `box_two` without success. I tried generating the form this way too, but this is not working:

> ```
> formset = modelformset_factory(
>     Item, form=ItemForm)(queryset=Item.objects.order_by(
>         'code__name').annotate(amount=Sum('box_one') + Sum('box_two')))
> ```

This issue is related to this previous one, but this new one is simpler:
[Pre-populate HTML form table from database using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158138/pre-populate-html-form-table-from-database-using-django)

Previous related issues at StackOverflow are very old and not working for me.

I'm using Django 2.0.2

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Current code:

*models.py*

```
class Code(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey(Code, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    box_one = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    box_two = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["code"]
```

*views.py*

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    description = CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['code', 'box_one', 'box_two']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        item = super(ItemForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        item.box_one = self.cleaned_data['box_one']
        item.box_two = self.cleaned_data['box_two']
        item.code.save()

    def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):
        if field_name == 'description' and hasattr(self.instance, 'code'):
            return self.instance.code.description
        else:
            return super(ItemForm, self).get_initial_for_field(
                field, field_name)


class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Item

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ItemListView, self).get_context_data()
        formset = modelformset_factory(Item, form=ItemForm)()
        data['formset'] = formset
        return data
```

*urls.py*

```
app_name = 'inventory'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

*item_list.html*

```
...
          <div>
            <form action="" method="post"></form>
            <table>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for form in formset %}
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            <th>{{ form.code.label_tag }}  </th>
                            <th>{{ form.description.label_tag }}  </th>
                            <th> <label>Amount:</label> </th>
                            <th>{{ form.box_one.label_tag }}  </th>
                            <th>{{ form.box_two.label_tag }}  </th>
                        {% endif %}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ form.code }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.amount }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.box_one }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.box_two }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                {% endfor %}

                <input type="submit" value="Update" />
            </table>
            </form>
          </div>
...
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve in the `save` method of `ItemForm`? Why do you add the field `description`? It belongs to `Code`. You should only attach an item (or items) to the code.

Comment: It was like this before moving from a simple form in a "item detail page" to a formset. It allowed me to save a single item in its page. Now I want to change it to be able to save all the fields in the formset

Comment: The method `save` of `ItemForm` makes no sense to me. First you call the parent method with `item = super().save(commit=False)` but you don't return `item`. Assigning values to `item.box_one` and `item.box_two` goes with the wind. At the end you're just trying to save an instance of the related `Code` model.

Comment: Can you include the code for your post method in your view that handles the submitted formset? Also please include any form errors on the forms, i.e. [`formset.errors`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation) from your `post` method. As alluded to by cezar, you're not doing anything useful in your `save` method, get rid of it altogether.

Comment: I know, that method was working before I move from a simple form to a formset as I said before. I don't have any post method implemented, because I don't know where or how I should do it. I'm sorry, but I never worked with formset before, so any help with this will be perfect.

Comment: @sytech Every save implementation I see for formsets uses a request parameter and then `if request.method == POST`... but in a class-based views, I don't know where to implement or add that

Comment: @AbelPaz please take a look at the docs on [handling forms with class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views). I'll update my answer regarding this.

Answer (score 4):

#### Annotating query with virtual column

`Sum` is an [aggregate expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions) and is not how you want to be annotating this query in this case. Instead, you should use an [F exrepssion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) to add the value of two numeric fields

```
qs.annotate(virtual_col=F('field_one') + F('field_two'))
```

So your corrected queryset would be

```
Item.objects.order_by('code__name').annotate(amount=F('box_one') + F('box_two'))
```

The answer provided by cezar works great if intend to use the property only for 'row-level' operations. However, if you intend to make a query based on `amount`, you need to annotate the query.

#### Saving the formset

You have not provided a `post` method in your view class. You'll need to provide one yourself since you're not inheriting from a generic view that provides one for you. See the docs on [Handling forms with class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views). You should also consider inheriting from a generic view that handles forms. For example `ListView` does not implement a `post` method, but `FormView` does.

Note that your template is also not rendering form errors. Since you're rendering the formset manually, you should consider adding the field errors (e.g. `{{ form.field.errors}}`) so problems with validation will be presented in the HTML. See the docs on [rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Additionally, you can log/print the errors in your `post` method. For example:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    formset = MyFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return SomeResponse
    else:
        print(formset.errors)
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then if the form does not validate you should see the errors in your console/logs.

Answer (score 3):

You're already on the right path. So you say you need a virtual column. You could define a virtual property in your model class, which won't be stored in the database table, nevertheless it will be accessible as any other property of the model class.

This is the code you should add to your model class `Item`:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # existing code

    @property
    def amount(self):
        return self.box_one + self.box_one
```

Now you could do something like:

```
item = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
print(item.box_one) # return for example 1
print(item.box_two) # return for example 2
print(item.amount) # it will return 3 (1 + 2 = 3)
```

EDIT:
Through the `ModelForm` we have access to the model instance and thus to all of its properties. When rendering a model form in a template we can access the properties like this:

```
{{ form.instance.amount }}
```

The idea behind the virtual property `amount` is to place the business logic in the model and follow the approach **fat models - thin controllers**. The `amount` as sum of `box_one` and `box_two` can be thus reused in different places without code duplication.

Comment: Mmmm... and how do you use the property from the formset at item_list.html?

Comment: @AbelPaz Please check the edit. The `ModelForm` holds the model instance (object) and can therefore access all of its properties. I hope will bring you to the right path.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. And what about the other issue? How to save all the form data when clicking the `Update` button?
My `save` method is not working at all.

Comment: This is a good solution to OP's problem. But one should note that one cannot query objects using a property. For example `Item.objects.filter(amount=x)` is not possible. They should be thought of as usable for 'row-level' operations only.

Comment: @sytech Thanks! That's a good point. Here is a workaround. Let's say you want to retrieve all objects with amount less than 10: `pk_list = [item.pk for item in Item.objects.all() if item.amount < 10]; qs = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list)`.

Comment: @cezar that works, but results in you querying for and iterating over every single row in the table, then querying it a second time to filter it. For a table of any significant size, you take a serious performance hit. It's no different really than if you did not have the property at all. That's why they should be thought of as useful for 'row-level' operations only. But it does fit well for OP's case, since I don't think OP needs to query on the property.

Comment: Thanks @sytech & cezar.
I'm still trying to figure out how to save the whole formset when clicking the "Update" button, but I can't make it work. Any idea?